# Scala - Enumeration with value parametrized

Tags: scala, types, enumeration

I'm wondering if its possible to have Enumerations with one value parametrized.

Something like:

```
object Animal extends Enumeration {
  val Dog = Value("dog")
  val Cat = Value("cat")
  val Other = Value(?)

  def create(value: String): Animal.Value = {
    Animal.values.find(_.toString == value).getOrElse(Other(value))
  }
}
```

And, for use, something like:

```
create("dog") // will return Animal.Dog
create("giraffe") // will return Animal.Other
create("dog").toString // will return "dog"
create("giraffe").toString // will return "giraffe"
```

That is, to be able to have some values typed, but to leave one free.

Thanks!!!
Lucas.

Comment: This sounds like a job for classes, not enumerations. An enumeration, by definition, is a *finite* collection of possible values. You're trying to get an infinite collection of possible values. [Case classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) would be a good place to start.

Comment: I get it. The problem I have is that these enumerators already exist in my app and in many places. And now it is necessary to add new ones without deploy. Sorry. Its a mess.

Comment: Understandable. Code maintenance is always a nightmare, but then the unfortunate answer I have to give you is no. This is not possible to do with enumerations alone. You're going to have to break some old code or simply abandon this part of the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to apologize for jumping the gun. I was thinking in Java terms, where an `enum` is a very rigid thing. Scala, however, is a bit more flexible in that regard. `Enumeration` does not stop us from extending the enumeration class ourselves.

**Disclaimer:** This is probably not a good idea. It works, but I don't know how it will behave with respect to serialization or the other nice properties that ordinary enumerations have. So if it works for you, great! But I can't promise that it's a *good* solution.

```
object Animal extends Enumeration {
  val Dog = Value("dog")
  val Cat = Value("cat")

  def create(value: String): Animal.Value = {
    Animal.values.find(_.toString == value).getOrElse(OtherAnimal(value))
  }
}

// Extending the enumeration class by hand and giving it a `String` argument.
case class OtherAnimal(name: String) extends Animal.Value {
  override def id = -1
  override def toString = name
}

println(Animal.create("dog").toString)     // dog
println(Animal.create("cat").toString)     // cat
println(Animal.create("giraffe").toString) // giraffe
```

Comment: And this doesn't break pattern matching or anything? Anyway, even if it breaks everything, it's funny nevertheless xD

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! It works.
I didn't test pattern matching because I don't need it.
The use of these enumerations is simple, but extensive.